# WinApi drawing in every frame

Tags: c++, c, animation, winapi, rendering

I want to draw a sine wave on every frame. In every frame, after drawing, the angle will be increased and I want to have a smooth wave moving effect, but I don't know how to achieve drawing in every frame.

This is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

HWND hwnd;
float t = 0.0f;

HANDLE tickThreadHandle;

DWORD WINAPI tickThreadProc(HANDLE handle)
{
    Sleep(50);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    RECT r;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &r);

    HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 255, 255));
    HPEN hOldPen = static_cast<HPEN>(SelectObject(hdc, hPen));

    int delay = 1000 / 50;

    while (true)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x<r.right; x += 5, t += 0.3f)
        {
            LineTo(hdc, x, sin(t) * 50 + 200);
        }

        t += 0.1f;
        Sleep(delay);
    }

    SelectObject(hdc, hOldPen);
    DeleteObject(hPen);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow)
{
    LPCTSTR lpszClassName = L"WNDCLASS";

    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    ZeroMemory(&wcex, sizeof(wcex));

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(wcex);
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.lpszClassName = lpszClassName;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 150));

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        NULL,
        lpszClassName,
        L"WINDOW",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        0,
        0,
        400,
        400,
        HWND_DESKTOP,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return -2;
    }

    //ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    //InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);

    MSG msg;
    //SendMessage(hwnd, WM_PAINT, NULL, NULL);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        /*RedrawWindow(hwnd, &windowRect, NULL, RDW_INTERNALPAINT);*/
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            tickThreadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, NULL, &tickThreadProc, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(NULL);
        }
        //case WM_PAINT:
        //{

        //}
        default:
        {
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried many strategies, in my last attempt I was trying to do another thread, and draw from there, but my window does not even show. I was trying to send to my window messages `WM_PAINT` too, or using `RedrawWindow` function but that gave me nothing. I know that I could use it in wrong way, please correct me and give me a hint what I could do.

Comment: I mean that I want to draw this sine wave about 50 frames per second, so I want to show 50 animation steps in one second as you can see in this line: `int delay = 1000 / 50;`

Comment: So it will not work on pure WinApi? If yes then what could you recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SetTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx) can be used (with a normal message loop) to paint the window in intervals as short as 16 milliseconds. Windows will send `WM_TIMER` message at each interval where you can invalidate the window.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        SetTimer(hwnd, 1, 20, NULL); 
        break;

    case WM_TIMER:
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        render(hwnd, hdc);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

The render function can be modified to use the `HDC` from paint function.

```
void render(HWND hwnd, HDC hdc)
{
    ...
    HBRUSH hbrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 150));
    HBRUSH oldbrush = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(hdc, hbrush);
    FillRect(hdc, &cr, hbrush); 
    ...
    SelectObject(hdc, oldbrush);
    DeleteObject(hbrush);
    //Sleep <== remove the Sleep function
}
```

Alternatively you can use the so called "gaming loop" with high resolution timers like `std::chrono` to invalidate the window at shorter intervals. `WM_PAINT` message can be handled as before.

Direct3D or OpenGL games may use a similar message loop and call a `render()` function, but in this case we can just call `InvalidateRect` to paint the window.

```
#include <chrono>
...

MSG msg = { 0 };
while(TRUE)
{
    if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) //<=== **** EDITED **** 
            break;
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {
        typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock hiresclock;
        static auto timer = hiresclock::now();
        auto milisec = (hiresclock::now() - timer).count() / 1000000;
        if(milisec > 20)
        {
            timer = hiresclock::now();
            //... draw
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The message loop has the same issue as the OP's implementation: It will lead to messages piling up, without being dispatched. Don't handle a single message per frame rendered. Instead, drain the entire queue before moving on to update the frame. `WM_QUIT` handling needs to go inside the `while(PeekMessage(...))` loop.

Comment: @IInspectable I didn't catch all that. I put `WM_QUIT` in the right place as you suggested. That should fix it!

Comment: That is exactly what I want, I didn't know that there are messages like WM_TIMER.

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue. You will still have messages piling up, if you handle just a single one per frame.

Comment: @IInspectable If I have standard loop and SetTimer with WM_TIMER, is this causing pilling up messages?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. The code does in fact drain the message queue and only renders a frame, when no more messages are available that need handling.

Comment: @Michael The standard loop (`while(GetMessage(...)){}`) is fine with `SetTimer`. For the next step, you might look at using a memory dc for these drawings.